# Failure to Render Waffle Charts in Rmarkdown using FontAwesome glyphs

Tags: r, r-markdown, font-awesome, waffle-chart

When running this code from an r markdown file:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r test}
library(extrafont)
library(waffle)
parts <- c(80, 30, 20, 10)
waffle(parts, rows=8, use_glyph="shield")


```
````

I'm getting the following warnings that look something like:

```
## Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
## Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x
## $y, : conversion failure on 'ï„2' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ef>
## Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x
## $y, : conversion failure on 'ï„2' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <84>
```

I've tried several things such as:

- using the latex fontawesome package.
- running the example here: [Compile RMarkdown PDF with Waffle Chart and Glyphs FAILURE. MWE included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454766/compile-rmarkdown-pdf-with-waffle-chart-and-glyphs-failure-mwe-included) (I had issues with quartz_pdf, perhaps become I'm on Windows?)
- using the fontawesome, emojifont, and emo r packages

Note that the glyphs *are* properly rendered when outputing an HTML file. They are also correctly rendered when just calling the waffle code in the console.

I can even render fontawesome symbols directly through the latex fontawesome package by typing something such as `\faAmazon`

I've sunken most of today in trying to figure this out (100% sunken cost fallacy at this point).

Edit: Just FYI incase anyone else runs into this. I rendered the chart as a .png, as a temporary file and called the image back. Still looking for the proper way to do this as I would assume I'm losing some image quality along the way.